# Mongo functions to create Collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to write Mongo function something like

```
{
    "_id" : "createCollection&Index",
    "value" : function (collectionName,field)
      {
         return db.getCollection(collectionName).createIndex( { "fileld" : 1 } )
      }
}
```

and stored this function in system collection and execute it from Mongo-Java Driver. I have tried it but it's not working. Is it possible to create this in Mongo and execute it using JavaCode?